# when i click a button then it will take me phones inbuilt Bluetooth setting

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I tried it but it only ask me to permission and it will start *Bluetooth* but it cannot give me the phones inbuilt *Bluetooth* option?

```
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
    showDisabled();
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below  code will help out of it:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent bluetoothOpen = new Intent();
        bluetoothOpen.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(bluetoothOpen);
    }
});
```

OR

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));
```